# How to animate a swell and color change for a custom view selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I have hierarchy of custom `UIView` objects. The leaf views are selectable. They have an `isSelected` property on them. When this is set to `YES`, the effect I want is for the view to change to my "selected" color immediately, and then to temporarily swell in size and then return to its original size. I *thought* the following code would do the trick:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green: 0.5 blue: 1 alpha: 1];
CGRect currentFrame = self.frame;
CGRect bigFrame = CGRectInset(currentFrame, -50, -50);
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 animations:^{
    self.frame = bigFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished ) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 animations:^{
            self.frame = currentFrame;
        }];
    }
}];
```

I've exaggerated the time and displacement here, because I was trying to see what's really happening. What happens, is that the color changes seems to be animated, so it slowly changes from its default whiteness of 0.93 to my blue. Furthermore, it doesn't grow in size. It just seems to translate down and to the right by the inset amount, and then return to the normal spot (rather than grow in all directions).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keyframe animations:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
// 200 is example side of the big view, but you can apply any formula to it. For example relative to superview, or screen bounds
CGFloat multiplier = 200 / MAX(self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width)
bounceAnimation.values =
@[@(1 - 0.1 * multiplier, 
  @(1 + 0.3 * multiplier), 
  @(1 + 0.1 * multiplier,
  @1.0];
bounceAnimation.duration = 0.25;
bounceAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
bounceAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:@"bounceAnimation"];
```

Comment: I've never used they keyframe variant before. Thanks! This mostly worked. It didn't behave unexpectedly at least. Two questions I have now though. 1)Using the transform makes the temporary size increase relative to the original size. That makes little guys just pop a little, and big guys really be big. I would rather have a uniform pixel "outset" of the frame. Is there an alternate way? I could reverse compute the scales to achieve the desired pixel offset I guess. 2)I can't find the docs for `CATransform3D`. I found functions for changing them. But wouldn't know where to go to find the .scale

Comment: To do the frames, I switched to the `bounds` keyPath (apparently, you're not supposed to animate frames of layers, but rather bounds and position, etc). And then built up an array of `NSValue` around `CGRect`s.

Comment: You can easy achieve it via calculating bounce values according to your frame before, look at the updates answer

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`? Like so...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 animations:^{
    // Update 1.3 to what ever works for you
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished ) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 animations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        }];
    }
}];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Comment: Hmmm... Produces a different result. If I slow the animation down (1s) and use a scale of 2, what it does is suddenly goes to half size and slowly zoom to normal, and then after 1s, it suddenly becomes 2x big and then slowly (for the other 1s) returns to the original size.

Comment: The superview of this view lays this view it in its `layoutSubviews`. Is that somehow getting involved with the animation?